# Common masterpage for multilple web applications

Tags: master-page, branding

Is there anyway we can use a common master page for multiple web application so that changes done in this master page will reflect in all the web applications.

Answer (score 1):

The best method I would think would be to package the masterpage up into a feature, then you can deploy it to all of the web applications.  When updates are made, the new feature is pushed out to all the web applications so that the changes are reflected everywhere.

A real dev/branding expert would know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

MasterPages should not change that often. For dynamic content, you should use PlaceHolders and DelegateControls and/or Publishing pages.

Comment: I did not say they change often :)